# how can I get the position of a checked box in relation to its group?

Tags: jquery

how can I get the position of a checked box in relation to its group?

I’ve tried creating for loops but couldn’t get it to work. After a day of research I thought by adding,

```
  var indexValue = ($(this).attr('tabindex'));
```

I could get the position of the checked box then use that value to select the correct item.. Can you please tell me what I’m doing wrong here?

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

         var $checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

         $(document).ready(function () {
             var nl = 4;
             var nos = $('#listTable #searchString').length;
             // alert(nos);
             $.each($checkboxes, function () {
                 if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                     //  alert('checked');
                     var indexValue = ($(this).attr('tabindex'));

                     $('#listTable .daylists').eq(indexValue).css('border', '2px dashed blue').val($('option:first', this).val());
                     $('#listTable .teacherlists').eq(indexValue).css('border', '2px dashed blue').val($('option:first', this).val());

                 }


             });

         });


    </script>
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.each($checkboxes, function(index, element) {
    // index is the position you are at within this loop, starts at 0
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 0):

Not having seen your HTML, you probably want to use [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

```
var i = $checkboxes.index();
```

or rely upon the index param passed to `each`:

```
$.each($checkboxes, function (i) {
     // i is your index
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the checkboxes are all siblings under a parent element, you can use:

```
$(this).index()
```